# Nix based OSes and drivers

Tags: linux, macos, drivers

I have a simple question about certain drivers and *nix based OSes such as MAC OS X and Debian . . ..
Is the reason why some devices like mice, keyboards, wireless adapter are able to plug and play is because they share a common driver such as Realtek or Broadcom that is already loaded onto the kernel?

Comment: Just to clarify, Debian is NOT Unix based OS.

Comment: @edvinas.me: It almost is. While Linux is not certified UNIX™ nor POSIX-compliant, it _is_ an Unix-like OS based on other Unix-like OSes of that time as well as documentation of POSIX interfaces...

Comment: Unix-like and Unix-based isn't the same thing, at least I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

Certain classes of USB devices use a generic interface – e.g. "Mass Storage" for disks, "Human Interface Device" for mice and keyboards – so the OS only needs a single driver. (Even though Windows wants to "install" every new flash drive, in reality it just uses the same .inf/.drv/.sys files for all of them.)

Other devices, like wireless adapters, require custom drivers, but they work simply because those drivers are already part of Linux. For example, the `ath9k.ko` Linux module handles all AR9* series Atheros wireless adapters.